# Apache Camel - Unable to propagate JMS Header Properties between Request - Response

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

I am trying to save a value on the Camel Exchange between a Request - Response invocation against a QPID endpoint.

You can see from my code that I set a Header (and Property) before i invoke the Endpoint. Upon return the same Header and Property Values are null.

I basically want to keep a track of the fileName and filePath so that I can write the results into the same location

Really struggling with this.

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class ProcessingRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    //@formatter:off
        from("file:/home/molko/in/?recursive=true&include=.*.txt")
            .log("File read from disk : ${file:name}")
            .doTry()
                .setHeader("JMSReplyTo", constant("response-1"; {create:always, node:{type:queue}}"))
                .setHeader("JMSCorrelationID", constant(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()))

                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                        final String fileParent = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileParent", String.class);
                        final String endPath = fileParent.substring(fileParent.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("endPath", endPath);
                        exchange.setProperty("endPath", endPath);
                    }

                })                  

                .to(amqp:request-1;{node:{type:queue}}?preserveMessageQos=true?exchangePattern=InOut")
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .log("Failed : ${file:name}")
                .log("${exception.stacktrace}")
            .stop();

        from("amqp:response-1; {create:always, node:{type:queue}}")
            .log("Received from qpid broker : ${date:now}")
            .doTry()
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                        byte[] response = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);

                        System.out.println("properties : " + exchange.getProperties());
                        System.out.println("headers : " + exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
                        }               
                    })              
                .to("file:/home/molko/out")
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .log("Failed from qpid brokre : ${date:now}")
                .log("${exception.stacktrace}")
            .stop();
    //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`includeAllJMSXProperties` is probably what you are looking for ,

> Camel 2.11.2/2.12: Whether to include all JMSXxxx properties when
>   mapping from JMS to Camel Message. When set to true properties such as
>   JMSXAppID, and JMSXUserID etc will be included. Note: If you are using
>   a custom headerFilterStrategy then this option does not apply.

Source : https://camel.apache.org/jms.html